# Create array of different dropboxes

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to create an array of different dropboxes

The result i'm looking for is this:

```
$array[0]="value of dropbox1,value of dropbox2,value of dropbox3";
$array[1]="value of dropbox4,value of dropbox5,value of dropbox6";
$array[2]="value of dropbox7,value of dropbox8,value of dropbox9";
$array[3]="value of dropbox10,value of dropbox11,value of dropbox12";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @doniyor could you give an example

Comment: you mean with dropbox the dropdown menu?

Comment: no how to make an array from the values from the dropdown menu like my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = array("value1", "value2", "value3");
$array[1] = array("value4", "value5", "value6");

echo $array[0][0];
```

Try this code here:

http://writecodeonline.com/php/